# Repairing broken links for new paths of layers to shapefiles using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I have an .mxd with broken link layers and each layer has a different new path.
I know the python script for repairing the broken links of the layers, but I want to put all the new paths of the layers and then let python do and finish all the process. The script that I have does it one at a time. I know if all the shapefiles are in one path then it's done by performing it once. but what if they al have different paths?

To clarify, let's say I have 3 layers with broken links and each one has a different new path now. I'd like to have a GUI with 3 inputs for the new paths altogether or let script do the process one by one and each time asking for the next path to input.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the GUI by itself doesn't know how many broken layers you have, the easiest way to do this might be through the Python promt with a script similar to the following (See the [Layer Class documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) for more on the replaceDataSource method):

```py
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd):
    print "Datasource %s does not exist" % lyr.dataSource
    workspace_path = raw_input("New Workspace: ")
    workspace_type = raw_input("Workspace type: ") #See http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/
    dataset_name = raw_input("Dataset name (enter for %s): " % lyr.datasetName)
    if len(dataset_name) == 0:
        dataset_name = lyr.datasetName

    #Note, there's no error checking above, so we set validate to True        
    arcpy.mapping.replaceDataSource(workspace_path, workspace_type, dataset_name, True)

#mxd.save() #uncomment if you want changes saved when the script finishes
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
Here's my code which does almost the same:

import arcpy
mapDoc=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
brokenLayer=arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mapDoc)[0]
path=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
brokenLayer.replaceDataSource(path)
arcpy.RefreshTOC()


but every time, you have to invoke this script and input a new path.
what I'm looking for is like creating maybe a loop according to the number of broken links that each one has a different path.